# Getting values of a variable filtered by the missing values of another variable in a dataset

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, na

I have a data set with age and income variables. The income column has some missing values. I want to write a code where I can get all the values of age variable for all missing values of income variable only i.e. the result of my code would display the ages where income value is NA. I was trying to do this using dplyr function but I am stuck. I know this is simple but I have been unable to do this. Could anyone suggest the code for this. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you add your code so people can see it and offer suggestions?

Comment: dat%%>%filter(??)%>%select(age). I am stuck in the filter function part, I don't know what to write here if i want to filter the data set "dat" containing missing values of income.

Comment: When you ask a question present example data and code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. `dat=data.frame(income=c(runif(5), rep(NA, 5)), age = c(rep(1:5, each=2)))` Then you can filter it
`dat %>% filter(is.na(income))`

Comment: Its simply `dat[is.na(dat$income),]`. No any package needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some test data:

```
data<-data.frame(Age   = c(23,28,27,31,42,26,48,23,32,31),
                 income = c(20000, NA, 30000, 25000, NA, NA, 35000, NA, 40000, 250000))
> data
   Age income
1   23  20000
2   28     NA
3   27  30000
4   31  25000
5   42     NA
6   26     NA
7   48  35000
8   23     NA
9   32  40000
10  31 250000
```

Explicitly using the `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)
data %>% filter(is.na(income))

  Age income
1  28     NA
2  42     NA
3  26     NA
4  23     NA
```